# Git - how to merge multiple repositories with common files?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-remote

So my problem is like this: I have 2 different repositories and I need to make a different, new one - containing files from these two. However the repositories share some files (main.c for example) which I want to merge manually... I've tried to merge repos with this tutorial: http://blog.caplin.com/2013/09/18/merging-two-git-repositories/, however I only get one "copy" of main.c. Maybe I don't understand how git works (I'm pretty new to it), but I really need git to give me two files, which then I can manually change and make into a new main.c... I hope I've made myself clear about my problem... I could just make two different working copies of those repositories, copy the content and make a new repo... But then the history would be lost, right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a repository with TWO remotes using `git add remote` - http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Clone the first remote to create the initial set of files locally - http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Then use git pull [remote2] to get the files in from the other repository - http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Then resolve any code conflicts.

Then, if desired,add a third remote for the new repo and push the code code to that.

Comment: I can't clone a remote, because it says **fatal: repository 'ps3' does not exist**. ps3 is the name of my first remote, which you want me to clone. I pulled it thought, via `git pull ps3 master` and it worked. However when I try to `git pull ps4 master` that's what I get:
`From *******...
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> p4/master
Already up-to-date.
`. And it's not up to date, because ps4 (my 2nd remote) has different main.c than my ps3...

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a central point. For project_a, this will be the default, your code repository in https://path.toyourproject.com/p/project_a. Start by checking it out and moving all of its contents into a subdirectory:

```
$ git clone https://path.toyourproject.com/p/project_a
$ cd project_a
$ mkdir project_a-cli
$ git mv * project_a-cli
$ git commit -a -m "Move."
```

Then you're ready to start tackling the merge of a secondary repository. For example, https://path.toyourproject.com/p/project.testers

**The first step is to pull in that secondary repository into your central point**

```
$ git remote add origin-testers https://code.google.com/p/project.testers
$ git fetch origin-testers
```

**check it out into a temporary branch and move all of its contents into a subdirectory**

```
$ git branch merge-testers origin-testers/master
$ mkdir project.testers-testers
$ git mv * project.testers-testers
$ git commit -a -m "Move."
```

**Merge the two repositories into one**

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge merge-testers
```

**Cleanup**

```
$ git branch -d merge-testers
$ git remote remove origin-testers
```

after that resolve the conflicts manually. you may want to install a visual diff tool for Git.

Comment: After going into project_a directory and making a new folder, when I try doing 
`git mv * project_a-cli`
I get a message saying **fatal: cannot move directory into itself, source=project_a-cli, destination=project_a-cli/project_a-cli**. So I moved files by `git mv *.c project_a-cli` and then it worked. The same fatal error happened after fetching 2nd repo and doing `git mv * project.testers-testers`. So I tried to do the same as before: `git mv *.c project.testers-testers`. However then I get another error: **fatal: bad source, source=*.c, destination=project.piask4-piask4/*.c**.

Comment: So it seems that after fetching 2nd repository I haven't gained any files from it... I tried to ignore it, checkouting master, then trying to merge merge-testers... But obviously it said that it's already up to date.